# How to "activate" ("select") a given Leaflet layer with the keyboard?

Tags: leaflet

I have the clickety-click GUI thing to switch layers. However, I often want to quickly swap between two layers without moving the cursor or my eyes. For this reason, I want to know how to select/activate a specific layer.

I've searched and searched but find not one mention of this (as is typical whenever I have any kind of issue).

Once I know how Leaflet wants to do this (maybe something like L.switchToLayer(someLayer);), I can then figure out how to assign each layer to a button such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc., although if you want to include that in your answer, I won't exactly complain!

(I never have any clue on which "category" (not tag) of this site to post stuff, but I'll try this one, I guess...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
var currentLayer;
var layers = [];

// Create your layers and push them to the layers array.

window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  var pressedKey = Number(e.key);

  // If button pressed is not a number, return.
  if (isNaN(pressedKey)) return;
  // If the pressed number is greater than the length of layers, return.
  if (pressedKey - 1 >= layers.length) return;
  // If currentLayer is set, remove it from the map.
  if (currentLayer) map.removeLayer(currentLayer);

  currentLayer = layers[pressedKey - 1];
  map.addLayer(currentLayer);
});
```

Here is [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/timiher/6/edit?js,output) with a working example. To test it out, first click on the map and then press the numbers 1 and 2 on your keyboard. Let me know if you'd like me to explain any more of the code.

Comment: Well... It seems like you never select a layer... only remove and re-add them? Can that really be the correct way? It seems like that will cause all sorts of issues? Is that really what happens when you click the GUI thing? It deletes and re-adds a layer each time? Still, I will naturally try your thing out and I'm grateful for it.

Comment: YES! It works! I didn't expect that, I must admit, but it does. So thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how the control feature works and whether my solution is the best way to do things but it's a workaround for what you're trying to accomplish I believe.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! :-)

Comment: You sure did. The only "complaint" I have (which may have nothing to do with your code) is that sometimes (I haven't been able to determine why it happens in spite of lots of testing), the 6 button (which is the last layer in my case) gets assigned to mean "zoom out one level" instead of "switch to that layer". Any idea why that would happen? It's a very minor problem and doesn't take away anything from your nice solution, but it would still be interesting to know why that happens, and it is a bit annoying when it happens.

Comment: The issue you're experiencing with the 6 button is discussed [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5766). A quick fix is to disable map interaction through the keyboard by setting the `keyboard` property to `false` when you instantiate your map: `var map = L.map('map', {keyboard: false})`. This disables buttons like +/- (and 6) for zoom control as well as the arrow keys for map panning.

Comment: Ah. Good, but not good that it disables arrow key panning... That's something I actually use.